# Include marginless pdf into article with altering margins

Tags: margins, geometry, pdfpages, double-sided

**Situation:** I've an article with altering page margins using the *twopage* option. The margins were set by the *geometry* package.

**Goal:** I want to inject a pdf, which has no margins at all, into my document. Furthermore, there has to be a *subsection* above that page. Necessarily, the margins of the page, where the pdf will be included, should be applied correctly. So, the marginless pdf needs to be downscaled in some way. Fortunately, my pdf just contains one page, so there is no need to apply an altering margin to the injected document.

**Approach:** For now, I've figured out, that the following code allows me to inject the page with an subsection-title.

```
\includepdf[pages={1},pagecommand={\subsection{Some Subsection Title}\label{sec:some_included_pdf}}]{complement/mysinglepagedocument.pdf}
```

I also figured out, that I could set an offset, but that would be static, so if my pdf gets included on an odd instead of an even page, it might happen that the margin does not fit anymore.

**Actual Question:** Any ideas or approaches to solve my issue?

Comment: If the image has no margin and the page should have the margins of the main document, you should just use `\includegraphics` instead if `\includepdf`.

Comment: Nevertheless: In twoside mode option `offset` moves to the outer margin and the top, so it's automatically correct.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thank you for your comments. After trying your first approach, I made the same conclusion as you've mentioned in your second comment. No idea, what I've done wrong before.